# preserving .deb files in archives directory

Tags: debian, apt

I wanted to preserve `.deb` files in the `archives` directory.

I created a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs` file with the following content:

```
Binary::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
```

But whenever I install a package using `apt`, the `.deb` files in the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory get deleted immediately post-installation.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake was that there was a typo in my config file.

My file read like this:

```
Binary::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
```

It should have been:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
```

The latter is the right thing.